# Bigquery: how to create table to accept bytes and string on same column?

Tags: google-bigquery

i have one issue in bigquery.

Problem statement:

we have a json file which we have to upload to bigquery table.
When it is loaded , a table will be created.
TABLE DDL:
CREATE TABLE vb_reports
(
records ARRAY<STRUCT<**rightData BYTES**, mismatchEnd INT64, mismatchStart INT64, fields ARRAY, rightRecLength INT64, leftRecLength INT64, segments ARRAY<STRUCT<**leftData BYTES**, diffDesc STRING, endIndex INT64, startIndex INT64, **rightData BYTES**, segmentName STRING, segmentID STRING>>, **leftData BYTES**, recordNumber INT64>>,
iterationID INT64,
jobSummary STRING,
jobName STRING
)

The rightData  and leftData columns are created as bytes type column.
**But when we load data from json file, these columns are interpreted as Strings and sometimes as Bytes.**
When the BigQuery Interprets these fields as String, then we get below error:

***Provided Schema does not match Table vb_reports Field records.segments.leftData has changed type from BYTES to STRING***

we are loading the json file from Bigquery consoles.
The problem is even though we have byte data , bigQuery Interprets it as String.

Please help us to create a column (leftData & rightData) with Bytes type which Accepts both Bytes & string Data Types.

Thanks in Advance.
hayyal

Comment: Would it be an option to have `leftdata` be interpreted as string and give the schema to DDL?

Comment: Hi Samuel, Thank you for your kind reply. we tried that option as well. But the problem is when we try to upload huge json file, BigQuery interprets some data as String and some as Bytes. even though the data is in HEX value for leftData and rightData. here i posted a simplified version of the table for easy understanding. we load json file data in the range of 100MB-2GB . which contains records in the range of 100k to 1 million records in each json file.