# Bigquery: uploading json data with Byte data gives error

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I have a small table created using:

```
create table test_table( 
rightData Bytes,
leftData Bytes,
iterationID integer);
```

And I am loading data into this table using the json file as shown below:

```
{
    "rightData": "F16060D6D7E260C607E40B1106B02000057C",
    "leftData": "C1D8D9D9F0F360F8F1F8606060D6D7E260C6F3F5F4F0F5C1C8C1D8F8F8606060F9F1F9",
    "iterationID": "10"
}
```

When I try to upload this json file, I get this error:

> Provided Schema does not match Table usis-mfb-cms-dev-npe-df0c:usis_mfb_compare_report.test_table. Field rightData has changed type from BYTES to STRING

Json file uploaded :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add schema while creating the table.

Like this
[image]

Comment: Hi Sakshi, Thanks for replying fast. the example which i showed is a simple one... Our data is more complicated. Also, Adding each column this way is practically not possible for every run of the job. we are looking for a way to accept the data which comes as hex values as Bytes or Strings. But in BigQuery, this is something which keeps fluctuating betweeen the two datatypes. So, what we are looking is for a consistent behaviour of bigQuery on auto detecting the column type.

Comment: if we give Strings, then it will throw the error for Bytes data . If we give bytes as column datatype, then also we see errors as String data types.  in either case, the column data which is coming in json is hexvalues only. The BigQuery is neither accepting the hexvalues as Bytes nor Strings for Big json files(100MB to 2 GB).

Comment: There is one more query which i posted with example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68620297/bigquery-how-to-create-table-to-accept-bytes-and-string-on-same-column  .. in this  link the table is simplified for understanding purpose.

Comment: Hi @hayyal_efx, this is intended behavior from Bigquery, If you're using auto-detect, biquery reads from the data you're uploading. 
It will detect datatype as Byte if your data have special any character like "/" etc or max length of data is at least 128 characters

Comment: The recommended workaround is to explicitly cast the field as a BYTE data type. For reference: [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/manually-changing-schemas#changing_a_columns_data_type)

Comment: Hi Sakshi, this recommended workaround is for select queries.
The operation what i am doing is uploading json file  to existing table which contains byte datatype as column.
And also the data in json file contains hexvalues , but nothing special characters likes "/"s  in it.

Comment: I understand your column contains hexvalues, but autodetect in Bigquery won't take it as byte datatype unless it has max length at least of 128 characters. In the workaround you can cast the datatype as byte and the store it as new table.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Sakshi for your guidance. I appreciate your time to help us.

As a workaround solution, we have appended "#" to start and end of all the byteData.
With this it BigQuery will treat all these byteData as String.
And then reworked on table creation by changing all BYTE columns to String.
This worked as a better solution for our requirement.

Regards
Nagaraj